# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/firebase/FirebaseApp

Tags: java, firebase, gradle, intellij-idea

When I put my minecraft plugin on my server I have this error :
I'm try to build a plugin who link my FireBase with my minecraft server but the plugin never load.

```
Error occurred while enabling RenbloodPlugin v1.0-SNAPSHOT (Is it up to date?)
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/firebase/FirebaseApp
        at fr.renblood.renbloodplugin.RenbloodPlugin.onEnable(RenbloodPlugin.java:13) ~[?:?]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin.setEnabled(JavaPlugin.java:273) ~[forge:?]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPluginLoader.enablePlugin(JavaPluginLoader.java:335) ~[forge:?]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.enablePlugin(SimplePluginManager.java:479) ~[forge:?]
        at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_16_R3.CraftServer.enablePlugin(CraftServer.java:502) ~[forge:7e29f765-296df566-9fb885e8]
        at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_16_R3.CraftServer.enablePlugins(CraftServer.java:414) ~[forge:7e29f765-296df566-9fb885e8]
        at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.func_240787_a_(MinecraftServer.java:427) ~[?:?]
        at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.func_240800_l__(MinecraftServer.java:347) ~[?:?]
        at net.minecraft.server.dedicated.DedicatedServer.func_71197_b(DedicatedServer.java:227) ~[?:?]
        at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.func_240802_v_(MinecraftServer.java:768) ~[?:?]
        at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.func_240783_a_(MinecraftServer.java:267) ~[?:?]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[?:?]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp
        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.PluginClassLoader.loadClass0(PluginClassLoader.java:178) ~[forge:?]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.PluginClassLoader.loadClass(PluginClassLoader.java:133) ~[forge:?]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521) ~[?:?]
        ... 12 more
```

I search but I didn't find anything to help.

My build.gradle :

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
}

group = 'fr.renblood'
version = '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        name = "spigotmc-repo"
        url = "https://hub.spigotmc.org/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/"
    }
    maven {
        name = "sonatype"
        url = "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/public/"
    }

}

dependencies {
    compileOnly "org.spigotmc:spigot-api:1.16.5-R0.1-SNAPSHOT"
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:9.2.0'

}

def targetJavaVersion = 11
java {
    def javaVersion = JavaVersion.toVersion(targetJavaVersion)
    sourceCompatibility = javaVersion
    targetCompatibility = javaVersion
    if (JavaVersion.current() < javaVersion) {
        toolchain.languageVersion = JavaLanguageVersion.of(targetJavaVersion)
    }
}

tasks.withType(JavaCompile).configureEach {
    if (targetJavaVersion >= 10 || JavaVersion.current().isJava10Compatible()) {
        options.release.set(targetJavaVersion)
    }
}

processResources {
    def props = [version: version]
    inputs.properties props
    filteringCharset 'UTF-8'
    filesMatching('plugin.yml') {
        expand props
    }
}
```

I change my version of FireBase

Comment: firebase app or firebase admin? check that dependency